# WinRT | C++ - HTTP Post File - The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect

Tags: c++, uwp, httprequest, c++-winrt

Basically I have two concerns, however the focus is on how to get around the certification.

I am having a hard time understanding how to make an HTTP post request in WinRT|C++. I have an ASP.Net-6-Web-Api-Project, which I have already been able to communicate with via a Python project and a C++ project (via Curl). I also tested the api via Postman. Every time doing so I had to ignore the validation of certification and it worked fine.

But now I have a WinRT/C++ project and have thrown together the following code. I want to be able to upload a file. In my case it is a point cloud in a .ply syntax as a string.

**My Concerns:**

1. In WinRT I got the expected error for invalid/untrusted certification, so I looked up what to do and ended up using `IgnorableServerCertificateErrors` from `HttpBaseProtocolFilter`, like you can see at the end of my code. But that did not fix my error. What am I missing? I still get the errors:

```
WinRT originate error - 0x80072F0D : 'The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect'.
WinRT originate error - 0x80190190 : 'The response status code does not indicate success: 400 ().'.
```

2. From the point of view of a developer familiar with WinRT, is the implementation correct in terms of an HTTP post request? Especially the lines
   `binaryContent.Headers().Append(L"Content-Type", L"image/jpeg");` and
   `HttpContentDispositionHeaderValue disposition{ L"form-data" };`
    And what are the follow lines for? Is this just about assigning arbitrary names?

```
disposition.Name(L"fileForUpload");
disposition.FileName(L"test.ply");
```

**Code:**

```
    void HL2ResearchMode::SendPLY(std::wstring const& pointCloud)
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"--- SendPLY()\n");

        if (pointCloud.size() == 0)
            return;

        init_apartment();

        auto buffer{
            winrt::Windows::Security::Cryptography::CryptographicBuffer::ConvertStringToBinary(
                pointCloud,
                winrt::Windows::Security::Cryptography::BinaryStringEncoding::Utf8
            )
        };

        winrt::Windows::Web::Http::HttpBufferContent binaryContent{ buffer };
        // binaryContent.Headers().Append(L"Content-Type", L"text/plain;charset=utf8");
        binaryContent.Headers().Append(L"Content-Type", L"image/jpeg");

        winrt::Windows::Web::Http::Headers::HttpContentDispositionHeaderValue disposition{ L"form-data" };
        //winrt::Windows::Web::Http::Headers::HttpContentDispositionHeaderValue disposition{ L"multipart/form-data" };
        binaryContent.Headers().ContentDisposition(disposition);
        disposition.Name(L"fileForUpload");
        disposition.FileName(L"test.ply");

        winrt::Windows::Web::Http::HttpMultipartFormDataContent postContent;
        postContent.Add(binaryContent);

        winrt::Windows::Web::Http::HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage;
        std::wstring httpResponseBody;

        try
        {
            // Send the POST request.
            winrt::Windows::Foundation::Uri requestUri{ L"https://192.168.178.41:5001/api/meshes/uploadPointCloud" };
            winrt::Windows::Web::Http::Filters::HttpBaseProtocolFilter myFilter;

            auto fu = myFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors();
            fu.Append(ChainValidationResult::Expired);
            fu.Append(ChainValidationResult::Untrusted);
            fu.Append(ChainValidationResult::InvalidName);
            fu.Append(ChainValidationResult::InvalidSignature);
            fu.Append(ChainValidationResult::InvalidCertificateAuthorityPolicy);

            winrt::Windows::Web::Http::HttpClient httpClient(myFilter);
            httpResponseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, postContent).get();
            httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            httpResponseBody = httpResponseMessage.Content().ReadAsStringAsync().get();
        }
        catch (winrt::hresult_error const& ex)
        {
            httpResponseBody = ex.message();
        }
        std::wcout << httpResponseBody;
    }
```

Comment: This is mushing up lots of unrelated issues. First up: None of this reads reasonable. If you're `POST`-ing a [PLY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) stream, why declare it as being a JPEG image? It isn't. Also, when performing asynchronous operations, why make them synchronous? There's `IAsyncAction` and `IAsyncOperation<T>` and C++ coroutines for that. As for the immediate issue, you may want to consider providing a [mcve] that doesn't include all those unrelated issues.

Comment: @IInspectable; about the JPEG image: If you scroll [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient) down to the title 'POST binary data over HTTP' you can see the comment 'You can use the 'image/jpeg' content type to represent any binary data; it's not necessarily an image file'

Comment: That's a comment, on C# code. Given that any arbitrary piece of C# code I've ever had the misfortune of reviewing is wrong, what are the odds that the comments would be the only thing that weren't? I mean, why would there be `application/octet-stream` if `image/jpeg` were the official content type for any kind of binary data?

Comment: hmm ok, so I'm gonna try another content type. And about the async stuff - I didnt know that, Im not familiar with c++ at all. I thought that this is async, so I'm also have to check that.